# AZ Custom Handler No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Trying to add a Custom Handler to a simple AZ Function project. AZF works ok locally at VSC before adding. After adding, F5 starts ok like before:

```
[2021-12-30T19:33:14.402Z] Startup operation 'a9550626-ee3e-1234-b254-9facc08a3890' completed.
Functions:
        select: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/select
```

then:

> For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
> [2021-12-30T19:33:16.324Z] Waiting for HttpWorker to be initialized.
> Request to: http://127.0.0.1:49774/ failing with exception message: No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it. (127.0.0.1:49774)

The port is random, next time can be 62974, then F5 stops itself.

Here is what's been added:

1. `customHandler` into root host.json.
2. a new folder `middleware` contains
   `app.js, myroute.js, host.json, mdw.js`

**root host.json**:

```
{
  ...
  "customHandler": {
    "description": {
      "defaultExecutablePath": "node",
      "defaultWorkerPath": "middleware/app.js"
    },
    "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
  }
}
```

**middleware/app.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3005;
app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log('================ My mdw is on 3005 ================');});
require("./myroute.js")(app);
```

**middleware/myroute.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const mdw = require("./mdw");
module.exports = app =>
{
    app.post("/api/testmdw",      mdw.mytest);
};
```

**middleware/mdw.js**:

```
async function mytest(req, res, next)
{
    const q = req;
    return res.json({mdw: "ok"});
}
module.exports = { mytest }
```

**middleware/host.json**:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following this [Blog](https://securecloud.blog/2021/01/04/express-js-middlewares-on-azure-functions-via-custom-handlers/) to use middleware on azure function via custom handler

Host.json

```
"customHandler": {
"description": {
  "defaultExecutablePath": "node",
  "defaultWorkerPath": "azexpresstest/app.js"
  },
  "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true,
  },
"extensions": {"http": {"routePrefix": ""}}
```

The `customHandler` section points to a target as defined by the `defaultExecutablePath`. The execution target may either be a command, executable, or file where the web server is implemented.

```
"customHandler": {
    "description": {
    "defaultExecutablePath": "app/handler.exe",
    "workingDirectory": "app"
}
…
```

Refer [here](https://www.bram.us/2020/03/19/azure-functions-custom-handlers/) for more information